# javascript count the digits in a number function problem

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to count the digits of a number and I found this function

```js
function countDigits(y){
  num = parseInt(y)
  count = 0
  if (num >= 1)
    ++count;

  while (num / 10 >= 1) {
    num /= 10;
    ++count;
  }
  
  return count;
}

console.log(countDigits("123456"));
console.log(countDigits("1"));
console.log(countDigits("012"));
```

I'm taking the input from a string digit y.

The problem with the function is when a number starts with a zero it doesn't count it?

Comment: What is the type of y?

Comment: Numbers can't start with a 0 (not including numbers between -1 and 1)

Comment: y is a string and I have to validate a phone number that is why I need the zero to be counted

Comment: @beans in that case, why not just get the length of the string (`y.length`)?

Comment: I needed to make sure they are all numbers too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your above function to count the 0s at the beginning of your number string. Though there can be other ways too.

```js
var y = '000102';
var num = parseInt(y);
var count = 0;

while (y[count] == '0') {
  ++count;
}
if (num >= 1) {
  ++count;
}

while (num / 10 >= 1) {
  num /= 10;
  ++count;
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

`parseInt` will ignore leading zeroes. You need something like:

```js
function countDigitsInANumericString(numeric) {
  return numeric.split('').filter((n) => Number.isFinite(parseInt(n))).length;
}

console.log(countDigitsInANumericString('0a1023')); // 5

console.log(countDigitsInANumericString('0123')); // 4

console.log(countDigitsInANumericString('123456')); // 6
```

Comment: It worked but I needed it without any string I should've made that clearer, thank you though

Comment: @gorak as of ES2015 it's probably better to use `Number.isNaN` to avoid some [edge cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#confusing_special-case_behavior) with the global `isNaN` function. But yes... that's a good alternative.

Comment: For anyone curious, the difference between `Number.isNaN` and `Number.isFinite` is that `Number.isNaN(Number.Infitiy)` returns `false`. In this case, it's hard to see how you end up with an infinite value so both would work.